# Cloning images with Python 3+Pillow in order to strip hidden metadata

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, metadata

I have a client that created several large PDFs, each containing hundreds of images within them. The images were created with a program that adds unique info to each file; random binary data was placed in some file headers, some files have data disguised as image artifacts, and general metadata in each image. While I'm unfamiliar with the program, I understand that it's a marketing software suite of some sort so I assume the data is used for tracking online distribution and analytics.

I have the source files used to create the PDFs and while I could open each image, clone its visual data, strip metadata and re-compress the images to remove the identification data, I would much rather automate the process using Pillow. The problem is, I'm worried I could miss something. The client is hoping to release the files from behind an online username, and he doesn't want the username tied to this program or its analytical tracking mechanisms.

So my question is this: how would I clone an image with Pillow in a way that would strip all identifying metadata? The image files are massive, ranging from 128MB to 2GB. All of the images are either PNG uncompressed or JPEG files with very mild compression. I'm not married to Pillow, so if there's a better software library (or standalone software) that better suits this, I'll use it instead.

Comment: Sounds as if someone failed to pay its dues to a marketing software....

Comment: Sounds somewhat dubious. Note that the tracking info may not only be in embedded images - there could be minor changes to word spacing/spelling or punctuation that make a document traceable.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic. Simply start coding a image-recompressor and metatag stripper in pillow - if you have problem come back with a specific one.

Answer (score 2):

Just use **ImageMagick** as installed on most Linux distros and available for macOS and Windows. So, in Terminal, strip the metadata from an input file and resave:

```
magick input.jpg -strip result.jpg
```

If you want to do all JPEGs in current directory:

```
magick mogrify -strip *.jpg
```

Or maybe you want to change the quality a little too:

```
magick mogrify -quality 82 -strip *.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying the pixel data to a new image should remove all metadata and compressing the image slightly as a jpeg should remove [steganographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) tracking data.

You may have to modify the load/copy/save methods to deal with large files.  Also pay attention to the PIL file size [limitations](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/reference/limits.html). Opacity in png files isn't handled here.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

picture_dir = ''

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(picture_dir):
    for f in files:
        ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
        if( ext in ['.jpg','.jpeg','.png'] ):
            full_path = os.path.join(subdir, f)
            im = Image.open(full_path)

            data = list(im.getdata())
            no_exif = Image.new('RGB', im.size) # not handling opacity
            no_exif.putdata(data) # should strip exif

            out_path = full_path.split(ext)[0] + 'clean.jpg'
            no_exif.save(out_path, 'JPEG', quality=95) # compressing should remove steganography
```